# Is it possible to power-on a VMWare Fusion virtual machine without opening the VMWare application (and other windows)?

Tags: macos, vmware, vmware-fusion

I always SSH into my virtual machine and don't use VMWare's virtual machine window/terminal after I am done setting up the VM. I find it annoying to always have the VMWare Fusion application open as well as the VM window, thus, I want to be able to silently start the VM from my terminal and do all other actions only through terminal.

I saw [this page on the VMWare website](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1020751) that talks of starting a VM with the command:

```
/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun start full/path/of/your/virtual/machine/bundle
```

That is a step in the right direction as I don't need to click anything to start my VM, however, it still opens the application and VM in windows.

When I used Virtual Box, I remember being able to do this with a command like:

```
VBoxManage startvm "VM name" --type headless
```

Is there a similar command that for VMWare that would allow me to run my VM headless?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try :

```
vmrun start full/path/of/your/virtual/machine/bundle nogui
```